# How to stopMAS properly in JaCaMo?

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I have a JaCaMo project where I'd like to stop the system when a believe is added as follow:

```
+winner <- .stopMAS.
```

I am doing like this in a pure Jason project, but in this JaCaMo project where I have an organization, after this stopMAS command an error is ocurring in CArtAgO API as bellow:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:350)
    at cartago.WorkspaceKernel.execOp(WorkspaceKernel.java:782)
    at cartago.WorkspaceKernel.execOp(WorkspaceKernel.java:600)
    at cartago.AgentBody.doAction(AgentBody.java:72)
    at cartago.CartagoSession.doAction(CartagoSession.java:86)
    at jacamo.infra.JaCaMoAgArch.stop(JaCaMoAgArch.java:198)
    at jason.architecture.AgArch.stop(AgArch.java:57)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.stopAg(CentralisedAgArch.java:113)
    at jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS.stopAgs(RunCentralisedMAS.java:728)
    at jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS.finish(RunCentralisedMAS.java:826)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedRuntimeServices.stopMAS(CentralisedRuntimeServices.java:110)
    at jason.stdlib.stopMAS.execute(stopMAS.java:44)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applyExecInt(TransitionSystem.java:736)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applySemanticRuleAct(TransitionSystem.java:237)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.act(TransitionSystem.java:1525)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.act(CentralisedAgArch.java:203)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.reasoningCycle(CentralisedAgArch.java:212)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.run(CentralisedAgArch.java:231)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
cartago.CartagoException: exec op exception.
    at cartago.WorkspaceKernel.execOp(WorkspaceKernel.java:786)
    at cartago.WorkspaceKernel.execOp(WorkspaceKernel.java:600)
    at cartago.AgentBody.doAction(AgentBody.java:72)
    at cartago.CartagoSession.doAction(CartagoSession.java:86)
    at jacamo.infra.JaCaMoAgArch.stop(JaCaMoAgArch.java:198)
    at jason.architecture.AgArch.stop(AgArch.java:57)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.stopAg(CentralisedAgArch.java:113)
    at jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS.stopAgs(RunCentralisedMAS.java:728)
    at jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS.finish(RunCentralisedMAS.java:826)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedRuntimeServices.stopMAS(CentralisedRuntimeServices.java:110)
    at jason.stdlib.stopMAS.execute(stopMAS.java:44)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applyExecInt(TransitionSystem.java:736)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applySemanticRuleAct(TransitionSystem.java:237)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.act(TransitionSystem.java:1525)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.act(CentralisedAgArch.java:203)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.reasoningCycle(CentralisedAgArch.java:212)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.run(CentralisedAgArch.java:231)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[GroupBoard] p1 has quit, role participant removed by the platform!
```

How to avoid this error? Is there anything I should do before this stopMAS command?

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore this message. The latest version of JaCaMo (0.7-SNAPSHOT) fixes this problem.